# MySQL Query improvement

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I need to filter an DB, but my selection is too big for the DBeaver that i'm using. Is it possible to make it different?

```
CustomersAffected IS NULL 
AND Node NOT LIKE 'CTA%' 
AND Node NOT LIKE 'OCO%' 
AND Node NOT LIKE 'SJC%' 
AND Node NOT LIKE 'MUA%' 
AND Summary NOT LIKE 'Device Not%' 
AND Summary NOT LIKE 'Wireless%' 
AND Description NOT LIKE 'CLI%'
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"my selection is too big"* ? You're getting too much results?

Comment: Then use something else, maybe the command line for example

Comment: I think some of those AND's should be OR's

Comment: Have literally no idea what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be compressed using REGEXP

```
CustomersAffected IS NULL
AND Node NOT REGEXP 'CTA|OCO|SJC|MUA'
AND Summary NOT REGEXP 'Device Not|Wireless'
AND Description NOT LIKE 'CLI%'
```